# in a computer vs on a computer

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-objects

> Important information can be stored in a computer

vs

> Important information can be stored on a computer

Also, can we use **stored and saved** alternatively/interchangebaly with computer.

E.g.

> Important information can be saved in a computer

Comment: Hey Aditya; I think you'll get faster and more detailed answers if you ask this question over at our sister site, [English Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: sure, thx for the referral and the link..it provided me the answer.

Comment: @Dan: I don't see why this question should be any more suitable for ELL than ELU. I find it quite intriguing that ["stored **on** a computer" has overtaken "stored **in** a computer"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stored+on+a+computer+at%2Cstored+in+a+computer+at&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstored%20on%20a%20computer%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstored%20in%20a%20computer%20at%3B%2Cc0) since home PC's became widespread. The corresponding usage with smartphones/stored phone directories would also be new and potentially interesting.

Comment: @Fumble, my comment was directed more at the OP as an English Learner than the question proper.

Comment: @Dan: oic. I can't say I think the answers on the original question are particularly enlightening (or even, *accurate*), but I'd say that in principle they're both On Topic here.